# OpenGL barrier() Function and Divergent Flow Control

Tags: opengl, shader, gpgpu

## Question

Is the use of `barrier()` permitted following, but outside of, divergent flow control?

## Details

Within an OpenGL 4.00 compliant Compute Shader, I'm doing some work that involves a divergent (ie not dynamically uniform) branch statement. Later in the same shader, I need to synchronize execution of all the invocations within that work group for the purposes of memory access. This is also good for efficiency, as I'd like them all back in lock-step with each other. However, after consulting the khronos.org wiki and refpages, I'm not clear on whether what I want to do is valid as per the standard (regardless of whether it works in practice).

From [this page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/barrier.xhtml), we see that:

> Calls to **barrier** may not be placed within any control flow.

From [this page](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader), we see that:

> `barrier()` can be called from flow-control, but it can only be called from uniform flow control. All expressions that lead to the evaluation of a `barrier()` must be dynamically uniform.

First, the apparent contradiction regarding flow control. I'm assuming that it is only divergent (within a work group) flow control that is disallowed?

Second, there seems to me to be some ambiguity here regarding calls to `barrier()` that occur *after* divergent flow control. Importantly, note again the assertion that "All expressions that **lead to** the evaluation of a barrier() must be dynamically uniform." Does this mean leading up to, or ... ? Some examples to help illustrate my confusion.

#### Example 1, valid:

```
void main() {
    // ... do some work here ...
    barrier(); // valid use case
    // ... do some more work ...
}
```

#### Example 2, valid:

```
void main() {
    if (IS_BEST_WORK_GROUP) { // dynamically uniform within work group
        // ... do some work here ...
        barrier(); // valid use case
        // ... do some more work ...
    }
}
```

#### Example 3, invalid:

```
void main() {
    if (IS_BEST_INVOCATION) { // divergent within work group
        // ... do some work here ...
        barrier(); // this is illegal
        // ... do some more work ...
    }
}
```

#### Example 4, ambiguous:

```
void main() {
    if (IS_BEST_INVOCATION) { // divergent within work group
        // ... do some work here ...
    }
    barrier(); // is this allowed?
                // it occurs after, but outside of, a divergent branch statement
    // ... do some more work ...
}
```

- If example 4 is indeed valid, where would I look to find this information in an unambiguous form?
- Alternatively, if it is invalid is there some other mechanism available to get all my invocations back into lock-step following a divergent branch condition?
- If no to both of the above, can this perhaps be accomplished in Vulkan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only declarative source is the [GLSL Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf).

Section 8.16 states:

> For **tessellation control shaders**, the barrier() function may only be placed inside the function main() of the tessellation control shader and may not be called within any control flow. [...]
>
> For **compute shaders**, the barrier() function may be placed within flow control, but that flow control must be uniform flow control.

Your Example 4 is perfectly fine since the call to `barrier` is not in any control flow. It doesn't matter what you do before the barrier as long as you make sure that all shader invocations reach the same barrier.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the pdf link, the original wording is very clear. Don't know how I missed that when looking.

Comment: A technicality comes to mind, would it be legal to place a barrier inside divergent flow control as long as that control *eventually* evaluates to true during a given execution (such as a condition inside a loop)? For example, some invocations taking the branch at iteration 4, others at iteration 5. My reading of §8.16 is that it is technically illegal, but my understanding of (current) hardware is that it should **always** work in practice.

Comment: From the spec, it is not allowed. But I've never tried it in practice.

Comment: This is an old question but to answer @AnOccasionalCashew doing such thing is technically illegal, but GLSL has a concept called "reconvergence". If the barrier happens after the reconvergence point then it is legal. There are recent SPIR-V exts that allow developers to tightly control reconvergence at the cost of some compiler optimizations in order to get the necessary guarantees for a barrier (and other stuff like subgroup operations) to work correctly in such scenario. See https://www.khronos.org/blog/khronos-releases-maximal-reconvergence-and-quad-control-extensions-for-vulkan-and-spir-v

Answer (score 2):

Some additional Nvidia specific information from the NV_compute_program5 extension:

> Section 2.X.8.Z, BAR:  Execution Barrier
>
> The BAR instruction synchronizes the execution of compute shader invocations within a local work group.  When a compute shader invocation executes the BAR instruction, it pauses until the same BAR instruction has been executed by all invocations in the current local work group.  Once all invocations have executed the BAR instruction, processing continues with the instruction following the BAR instruction.
>
> There is no compile-time restriction on the locations in a program where BAR is allowed.  However, BAR instructions are not allowed in divergent flow control; if any compute shader invocation in the work group executes the BAR instruction, all compute shaders invocations must execute the instruction.  Results of executing a BAR instruction are undefined and can result in application hangs and/or program termination if the instruction is issued:
>
> - inside any IF/ELSE/ENDIF block where the results of the condition evaluated by the IF instruction are not identical across the work group;
> - **inside any iteration of REP/ENDREP block where at least one invocation in the work group has skipped to the next iteration using the CONT instruction, exited the loop using a BRK or RET instruction, or exited the loop due to having completed the requested number of loop iterations**; or
> - inside any subroutine (including main) where at least one invocation in the work group has exited the subroutine using the RET instruction.